# Como Mudar IFs Para For

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho 3 dropdown's com valores iguais (0,1, 2 e 3).
Aonde 0 é 'Selecione uma colaborador'
1 é 'Fábia'
2 é 'Helio'
3 é 'Sueli'
Tenho que selecionar um valor em um dos dropdown e sumir dos outros.
Exemplo:
Seleciono Sueli no primeiro DropDown e tem que sumir do Segundo e Terceiro, porem nesse segundo e terceiro tem que aparecer  Fábio e Helio no Segundo  e  Fabia e Helio no Terceiro.
E quando seleciono um desses nomes no Segundo e terceiro tem que moldar os 3 dropdowns de acordo com essa regra.
Uma coisa que tambem tem que acontecer é quando seleciono o item (valor 0, 'Selecione um colaborador'), tem que voltar para todos os outros dropdowns.
Eu consegui fazer com IFs mas ta gigante.
A questão é que não estou sabendo fazer por 'For'. 
Queria uma luz. Uma ajuda para poder aprender.
Se alguem puder me ajudar eu agradeceria muito.
Fiz assim:

```js
function fnFuncao() {

 
 var varField_idFacilitador1 = $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option:selected").val(); 
 var varField_idFacilitador2 = $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option:selected").val();
 var varField_idFacilitador3 = $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option:selected").val();

 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0)){
 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='0']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show(); 
  
 } 
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0)){

  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='0']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show(); 
  
 }

 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){

  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='0']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show(); 
  
 }  
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(1)){

  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='0']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador1+"]").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador1+"]").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador1+"]").hide(); 
  
 }
 if(parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(2)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='0']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador1+"]").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador1+"]").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador1+"]").hide(); 
 }
 if(parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(3)){

  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='0']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador1+"]").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador1+"]").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador1+"]").hide(); 
 }
 
 

 if  (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(1)){ 
 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='0']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador2+"]").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador2+"]").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador2+"]").hide(); 
  
 }
 if(parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(2)){
 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='0']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador2+"]").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador2+"]").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador2+"]").hide(); 
 }
 if(parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(3)){
 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='0']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador2+"]").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador2+"]").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador2+"]").hide(); 
 } 
 
 
 if  (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(1)){
 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='0']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador3+"]").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador3+"]").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador3+"]").hide(); 
  
 }
 if(parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(2)){
 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='0']").show();   
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador3+"]").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador3+"]").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador3+"]").hide(); 
 }
 if(parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(3)){
 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='0']").show();   
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador3+"]").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador3+"]").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value="+varField_idFacilitador3+"]").hide(); 
 }  
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='0']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='0']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='0']").show();   
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 }

 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(1) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").hide();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 }
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(2) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 }

 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(3) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").hide();  
 } 
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(1) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").hide();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 }
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(2) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 }

 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(3) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").hide();  
 }  
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(1)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 }
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(2)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 }

 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(3)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 }  
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(1) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(2)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").hide();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 } 
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(1) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(2)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").hide();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 } 

 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(2) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(3) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").hide();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").hide();  
 } 
 
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(1) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(3) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").hide();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").hide();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").hide();  
 } 
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(2) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(1)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 }  
 
 if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(3) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(1)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").hide();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").hide();  
 } 

  if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(1) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(3)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").hide();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").hide(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").hide();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 } 
 
  if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(1) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(2)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").show(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").hide();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 }  
   
  if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(3) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(2) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").hide(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").hide();  
 } 
 
  if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(3) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(1) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(0)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").hide(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").hide();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").hide();  
 } 
 
 
  if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(2) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(3)){
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").hide();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").hide(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").show();  
 } 

  if (parseInt(varField_idFacilitador1) == parseInt(3) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador2) == parseInt(0) && parseInt(varField_idFacilitador3) == parseInt(2)){
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='1']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='2']").hide();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value='3']").show();
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='1']").show(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='2']").hide(); 
  $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value='3']").hide(); 
  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='1']").show();  
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='2']").show();
  $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value='3']").hide();  
 }  
   
  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="varField_idFacilitador1" onChange="fnFuncao(this.value);">
  <option value="0">Selecione o Colaborador 1</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="varField_idFacilitador2" onChange="fnFuncao(this.value);">
  <option value="0">Selecione o Colaborador 2</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="varField_idFacilitador3" onChange="fnFuncao(this.value);">
  <option value="0">Selecione o Colaborador 3</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Existe uma maneira com menos código e mais dinâmica de se fazer esse código?

Comment: Edita a pergunta e coloca o HTML por favor.

Comment: Laercio o Html são 3 Dropdowns com 3 valores iguais: 
Os Valores São:
id   Nome  Nome do campo
1    Fábia   varField_idFacilitador1 
2    Helio    varField_idFacilitador2
3    Sueli    varField_idFacilitador3

Comment: coloca o html mano ... pfvr

Comment: o que é isso ` option:selected ` ?

Comment: mais uma coisa, por que tantos ` if ` ? usa ` else if `

Comment: Então essa é a questão. quero fazer um Loop para passar pelos valores e ir verificando. Mas não estou conseguindo fazer.
option:selected é JQuery. É a forma como ele trata o <select option>
Ja esta em Html só que na parte de JS/JQUERY.

varField_idFacilitador1  é o DropDown 1
varField_idFacilitador2  é o DropDown 2
varField_idFacilitador3  é o DrooDown 3

Comment: PRECISAMOS do HTML

Comment: Coloquei o Html

Comment: Vi que você usa `.hide()` para esconder um `<option>`. O problema disso é que isso não funciona no IE (funciona no Chrome, acho que Firefox tb e não testei no Opera)... sendo assim, seria melhor fazer como propôs o @bfavaretto, em vez de ocultar, desabilitar.. ou então, se fizer questão de ocultar mesmo sem usar `.hide()`, uma ideia seria criar uma array pra cada `<select>` e cada vez que uma opção é selecionada, recriar dinamicamente o `<select>` puxando os valores da sua respectiva array, ignorando o valor que é para ignorar.

Comment: Mas o IE aqui não vai ter problema. E eu to escondendo o valor do Option pois aqui terá que ser assim.  Mas nesse caso seria array composto?

Comment: Agora querem aqui com 4 valores por DropDown. Tipo: Fabia, Helio, Sueli, e Lucas.
E como vem do banco de dados pode ter infinitos registros por dropdown.

Comment: Ate ai tudo bem pois esta dinâmico e vindo do banco. Porem não to conseguindo voltar os valores quando seleciona a opção 0("selecione").

Comment: @DvD  Cara to perdidaço... E me botaram contra a parede aqui. Olha aonde cheguei:
https://jsfiddle.net/toewrmox/88/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra te dar um start, porque tem muito o que melhorar nesse meu código:

```js
var indisponiveis = [];
$('.select').on('change', function(e) {
  var _select = this;
  var select = $(this);
  var valor = select.val();

  var preenchidos = $('.select').filter( function(i, el){ return el.value > 0 } );
  indisponiveis = $.map(preenchidos, function(el){ return +el.value } ); 
  
  $('.select').each(function(i, el) {
    if(el !== _select) {
       $(el).find('option').each(function(i, op) {
         if(indisponiveis.indexOf(+op.value) > -1) {
           $(op).attr('disabled', true);
         } else {
           $(op).attr('disabled', false);
         }
      });
    } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1" class="select">
  <option value="0">selecione</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="s2" class="select">
  <option value="0">selecione</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="s3" class="select">
  <option value="0">selecione</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Valeu bfavaretto.
Deu uma boa clareada aqui.
Vou ver se consigo colocar a parte de recuperar os valores tambem pois tem que fazer update pelo asp tambem ao invés de só inserir. Mas deu pra dar uma boa Clareada.

Comment: Mudou tudo aqui.
Agora querem aqui com 4 valores por DropDown. Tipo: Fabia, Helio, Sueli, e Lucas.
E como vem do banco de dados pode ter infinitos registros por dropdown.
Ate ai tudo bem. Porem nao volta os valores.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz da seguinte forma abaixo.
Só que agora não consigo fazer ele mostrar novamente.
Encalhei aqui agora.

```js
 $('.select').on('change', function(e) {
  var _select = this;
  var select = $(this);
  var valor = select.val();
  
  
  var $combo1 = $("#varField_idFacilitador1");
 var $combo2 = $("#varField_idFacilitador2");
 var $combo3 = $("#varField_idFacilitador3");
  
  var indisponiveis = [];
  
  var preenchidos = $('.select').filter( function(i, el){ return el.value > 0 } );
  indisponiveis = $.map(preenchidos, function(el){ return +el.value } ); 
  
 
  $(".select").each(function(i, el){
    if(el !== _select) {
       $(el).find('option').each(function(i, op) {                                          if(indisponiveis.indexOf(+op.value) > -1) {
          $("#varField_idFacilitador1 option[value="+valor+"]").hide();
            $("#varField_idFacilitador2 option[value="+valor+"]").hide();
            $("#varField_idFacilitador3 option[value="+valor+"]").hide();
       }else{
   
            }
          })
      }
    });
   
     
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="varField_idFacilitador1" class="select" >
  <option value="0">Selecione o Colaborador 1</option>
  <option value="1">Fábia</option>
  <option value="2">Hélio</option>
  <option value="3">Sueli</option>
  <option value="4">Lucas</option>  
</select>

<select id="varField_idFacilitador2" class="select" >
  <option value="0">Selecione o Colaborador 2</option>
  <option value="1">Fábia</option>
  <option value="2">Hélio</option>
  <option value="3">Sueli</option>
  <option value="4">Lucas</option>   
</select>

<select id="varField_idFacilitador3" class="select" >
  <option value="0">Selecione o Colaborador 3</option>
  <option value="1">Fábia</option>
  <option value="2">Hélio</option>
  <option value="3">Sueli</option>
  <option value="4">Lucas</option>   
</select>
```